# Loading a script that depends on other methods loaded to page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I got a web site that sometimes his ajax requests returns some inline scripts (javascript) those scripts depends on methods loaded on the page initial request. for example consider a methods that pops a message to the user, and an ajax request that uses this method.

My initial page request loads those scripts asynchronously, so there is a possibility that an ajax request will return a response before main script finish loading and the method 'notify' did not load yet, is there any way to wait or check if this finish loading? I thought using $(window).load() but I guess this will fire only once.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using async as opposed to defer?  Seems like defer would be be a good idea since your scripts have dependencies on the main page.

Comment: @Tibrogargan I can name some reasons for you if you interested :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easest way - do something like in all async loaded script:

```
(function() {
function myModuleRun() {
 //do what module does
}

if (typeof window.myMainScriptLoaded === 'function') {
    window.myModuleLoaded(myModuleRun);
} else {
   window.loadedQueue = window.loadedQueue || [];
   window.loadedQueue.push(myModuleRun)
}
})();
```

in main script:

```
window.myModuleLoaded(module) {
  // do what you want to do when module loaded;
}

// use "for" loop, if you need to support older browsers.
window.loadedQueue.forEach(window.myModuleLoaded);
```